# efficient IP scanner in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, networking, ping

trying to do an IP scan in python in a time efficient manner .. I am trying to scan 192.168.0.0/20 and ~1500 hosts are alive .. trying to create something that runs in under a minute of two .. the following is my current code: .. Any suggestions? This code doesn't seem to be very efficient ..

```
def check_ping(hostname):
  response = os.system("ping -c 1 -W 1 " + hostname+" >/dev/null 2>&1")
  if response == 0:
      print hostname
      pingstatus = True
  else:
      pingstatus = False

  return pingstatus

def ipscan():
 output_ip = []
 thehost = "192.168."
 for i in range(0,16):
    host = thehost + str(i) + "."
    for j in  range(0,256):
        newhost = host + str(j)
        output_ip.append(newhost)
        newhost = host

  return output_ip

hosts = ipscan()
num_hosts = len(hosts)
for k in range(num_hosts):
   temp = hosts[k]
   t=threading.Thread(target=check_ping, args=(temp,))
   t.start()
```

Comment: Have a look at netmiko https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko.html

Comment: "_I am trying to scan 192.168.0.0/24 and ~1500 hosts are alive._" That is not actually possible. A `/24` network has only `254` usable host addresses. Also, you must remember that `/24` is only one possible network size, and you need to determine the size of the network first. Also, as you move toward IPv6, understand that the standard IPv6 network is a `/64`, and it would take you over 584,000 years! to scan such a network if you could scan 1,000,000 addresses per second (unlikely).

Comment: @RonMaupin my bad .. i meant /20

Comment: As you get to smaller prefixes, you will have a lot more hosts to scan. It becomes impractical, and you need to think about what you are trying to do, and if there is a different way. See the [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/369973). You may want to think about a solution outside the box, but you need to explain why you want to do this so that we can see if there is a better way.

Comment: @RonMaupin I am managing a cryptocurrency mining server farm with ~1500 Linux based servers. I have written code to help me scan the network, access the servers and retrieve information from them - currently working on making my IP scan more efficient - its the only aspect that's slowing things down

Comment: Maybe you should start with the DNS to create a list of hosts (servers) to check, rather than trying to scan an entire network. There are tools for server maintenance that probably make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ipaddress.hosts(), it return iterator over usable hosts in the network, after that you can iterate through it. It may be better be